# Add background image to individual fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have an app with multiple `fragments` and I would like to know how to add a background that is different for each `fragment`. The layout I am using has scrollable tabs which all use the same xml file. I also have a `MainActivity` that sets the view and an `adapter` for each `fragment`. I know you can add a background using the xml file with `android:background` or something of the sort as well as setting it to the view in the main activity but I can't figure out how to do it to each tab. Thank you for any help!

Comment: When you create those tab fragments, pass to them through a `Bundle` a int value or something else indicating the target background. You could then use `getArguments()` in the `onCreateView()` method to see what value was passed in and set the proper background.

Comment: I don't understand your question: you want to change layout on Fragment or on Tab? Maybe posting your layout (or an image) will be more helpful.

Comment: I want each fragment to have a different background, so that when you either swipe or press a different tab the background of the whole page changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add background to fragment, you have to wrap it in some container

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.simplefragmentexample.LayOutOne"
            android:id="@+id/frag_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If you wish to use same xml file, you should set images programmatically
`LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout01);
l.setBackground(Image);`

or use several xmls with `android:background`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the root View of the fragment with the Fragment [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) method. Then you can set the background of the View using one of the [setBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) methods of the View. For example to set a random background color to each fragment:

```
for ( Fragment f : fragments ) {
    f.getView().setBackgroundColor ( (new Random()).nextInt() );
}
```

PS: I never used fragments, therefore my answer could be wrong.

Comment: Hey Andrea,thanks for the answer. Could you please have a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181193/changing-background-image-of-current-fragment-in-viewpager#comment31893915_21181193 I'm having trouble with setting background image, when I do  f.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image) it doesn't change, similarly when i do f.getView().getBackground() it returns null.